# Как отсортировать объект по ключу в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как отсортировать объекты по ключам в обратном порядке.

```js
const arr = [
    { id: 1, score: "12" },
    { id: 2, score: "8" },
    { id: 3, score: "4" },
    { id: 4, score: "8" }
]

const func = arr.reduce((group, product) => {
    const { score } = product;
    group[score] = group[score] ?? [];
    group[score].push(product);
    return group;
}, {});

console.log(func)
```

на данный момент они отображаются в обычном порядке. А нужно, чтобы начиналось с большего ключа и переходило к меньшему. В консоль должно выводиться

```js
{
    "12": [{ id: 1, score: "12" }],
    "8": [{ id: 2, score: "8" }, { id: 4, score: "8" }],
    "4": [{ id: 3, score: "4" }]
}
```

Comment: У объектов всегда будет именно так. Этого не изменить... Так чтопри выводе тебе придётся читать с конца (хотя не уверен что у объектов есть на это методы)

Comment: Единственный вариант - это сделать именно простой массив. А его уже отсортировывать по score из первого субэлемента

Comment: Ещё вариант достать отсюда ключи и сложить в массив. Отсортировать массив в обратном порядке. А потом При выводе где-либо, делать цикл именно по этому отсортированному массиву, но доставать данные уже из объекта))

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: Если использовать `Map` - там порядок следования будет именно такой как данные добавлялись. ;)

Comment: @ksa это не то. В этом и смысл, что порядок изначально неизвестен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объектов всегда будет именно так. Этого не изменить... Так что придётся придумывать обходные пути. Например достать из объекта ключи и сложить в массив. Отсортировать массив в обратном порядке. А потом при выводе где-либо, делать цикл именно по этому отсортированному массиву, но доставать данные уже из объекта:

```js
let obj = {
    "12": [{ id: 1, score: "12" }],
    "8": [{ id: 2, score: "8" }, { id: 4, score: "8" }],
    "4": [{ id: 3, score: "4" }]
};

let arr = Object.keys(obj);
arr.sort((a, b) => +b - +a);

for (let element of arr) {
    console.log(`Значения по ключу с номером ${element}:`,  obj[element]);
}
```